# Contains method for a slice

Tags: go, slice

Is there anything similar to a `slice.contains(object)` method in Go without having to do a search through each element in a slice?

Comment: https://github.com/forestgiant/sliceutil

Comment: Try never to use a third-party package for such a work, like @Rodrigo you offered. It makes you code bulky and fragile

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/B1qGeOLI9Na

Comment: There is no possible way to search a slice without visiting every element, so it will always be O(N).  If you need scalability, a slice is the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Mostafa has already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10485970/) that such a method is trivial to write, and mkb gave you a hint to use the binary search from the sort package. But if you are going to do a lot of such contains checks, you might also consider using a map instead.

It's trivial to check if a specific map key exists by using the `value, ok := yourmap[key]` idiom. Since you aren't interested in the value, you might also create a `map[string]struct{}` for example. Using an empty `struct{}` here has the advantage that it doesn't require any additional space and Go's internal map type is optimized for that kind of values. Therefore, `map[string] struct{}` is a popular choice for sets in the Go world.

Comment: Also note, that you have to write `struct{}{}` to get the value of the empty struct so that you can pass it to your map when you want to add an element. Just try it, and if you encounter any problems, feel free to ask. You can also use Mostafa's solution if that's easier for you to understand (unless you have huge amounts of data).

Comment: Solution is simple, that's true. But what it takes to add such basic functionality into runtime? I haven't found such issues in Go repo on github. That's sad and strange.

Comment: How does `map[string] bool` compare with `map[string] struct{}`. `map[string] struct{}` seems like a hack especially initializing an empty struct `struct {}{}`

Comment: @IgorPetrov agreed, I'm surprised such a basic feature is not in the runtime already.

Comment: Ridiculous that you have to add this yourself.

Comment: How about `map[string]interface{}` with `nil` values? Will empty `interface{}`s be optimized by compiler?

Comment: See below for @Adolfo's answer regarding using slices.Contains() in Go 1.18+. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains

Comment: IMHO an answer to as yes/no question should start with yes or no and not with whitewashing the missing solution. This is not politics.

Answer (score 342):

No, such method does not exist, but is trivial to write:

```
func contains(s []int, e int) bool {
    for _, a := range s {
        if a == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

You can use a map if that lookup is an important part of your code, but maps have cost too.

Comment: Actually it's not trivial, because you have to write one for each type that you use, and because there's no overloading, you have to name each function differently, like in C. append() can work generically because it has special runtime support. A generic contains would be useful for the same reason, but really the generic solution is just generics support in the language.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood will this actually work with interfaces?

Comment: @OryBand it would, but not not with `==`, you must use http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual

Comment: trivial == 7 lines of code including 1 loop 1 branch if statement and 1 comparison? I think I'm missing something here ...

Comment: But why not add these in go core itself?

Comment: This might come to go core with generics.

Comment: What's the point of Go if it's a pain like C in such regard... If `contains` is so trivial, it should be self explanatory to add it to the standard library.

Comment: Fortunately you did not say, there is none *because* it is trivial to do a workaround, like so many others do. A workaround is never as trivial as a solution and even over ten years later in 2023 the solution is still experimental.

Comment: every time someone needs an extremely common function in go: "it's not there but it's easy to write it yourself"

Answer (score 281):

As of Go 1.21, you can use the stdlib [`slices` package](https://pkg.go.dev/slices) which was promoted from the experimental package previously mentioned.

```
import  "slices"

things := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
slices.Contains(things, "foo") // true
```

---

Original Answer:

Starting with Go 1.18, you can use the `slices` package –  specifically the generic `Contains` function:
https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains.

```
go get golang.org/x/exp/slices
```

```
import  "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
```

```
things := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
slices.Contains(things, "foo") // true
```

Note that since this is outside the stdlib as an experimental package, it is not bound to the Go 1 Compatibility Promise™ and may change before being formally added to the stdlib.

Comment: unfortunately you cannot use Go 1.18 with older versions of macOS

Comment: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Got above error during `go get`

Answer (score 58):

With Go 1.18+ we could use generics.

```golang
func Contains[T comparable](s []T, e T) bool {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Go is my favorite language because I love creating utilities from scratch that other languages offers OOTB.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I realize you're being facetious, and I do also agree that this should be in the stdlib, but generics were just introduced to Go. I prefer a language that is very deliberate about the features it introduces and remains relatively simple. I'm hopeful that over time this will be added to Golang.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=9m28s

Comment: I would rather spend effort in writing business logic than writing utilities.

Comment: It seems like in golang they are trading simplicity in language implementation for additional complexity for anyone using it.  I'm assuming every golang developer simply has all of the basic functionality implemented somewhere and copies and pastes it between their projects.  It's basically Javascript all over again, except code quality is higher due to the high barrier to entry

Comment: No need to roll your own. Since Go 1.19 you can use "golang.org/x/exp/slices" - https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains

Answer (score 27):

The [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package provides the building blocks if your slice is sorted or you are willing to sort it.

```
input := []string{"bird", "apple", "ocean", "fork", "anchor"}
sort.Strings(input)

fmt.Println(contains(input, "apple")) // true
fmt.Println(contains(input, "grow"))  // false

...

func contains(s []string, searchterm string) bool {
    i := sort.SearchStrings(s, searchterm)
    return i < len(s) && s[i] == searchterm
}
```

`SearchString` promises to return `the index to insert x if x is not present (it could be len(a))`, so a check of that reveals whether the string is contained the sorted slice.

Comment: In terms of time, the regular search is `O(n)` and this solution makes it `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: @plesiv it’s a binary search, AFAICS. Wouldn’t that make it O(log n)?

Comment: yes, binary-search and the function `contains` are `O(log(n))`, but the overall approach is `O(n*log(n))` due to the sort.

Comment: @plesiv Yes that's true for a single search, but if searching many times, say n times, then it's O(n + n * log(n)) vs O(n * n).  Henrik's answer shows searching more than one time.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of using a `slice`, `map` may be a better solution.

simple example:

```
package main

import "fmt"


func contains(slice []string, item string) bool {
    set := make(map[string]struct{}, len(slice))
    for _, s := range slice {
        set[s] = struct{}{}
    }

    _, ok := set[item] 
    return ok
}

func main() {

    s := []string{"a", "b"}
    s1 := "a"
    fmt.Println(contains(s, s1))

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/CEG6cu4JTf

Comment: In its current form this code offers no benefit, since there is no point in constructing a map from a slice if you are only going to use it once. — To be useful, this code should rather provide a function `sliceToMap` that does all the preparation. After that, querying the map is trivial and efficient.

Comment: You are creating a map by iterating the slice, it is double the work, more code, less efficient

Answer (score 19):

If the slice is sorted, there is a binary search implemented in [the `sort` package](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search).

Answer (score 9):

```
func Contain(target interface{}, list interface{}) (bool, int) {
    if reflect.TypeOf(list).Kind() == reflect.Slice || reflect.TypeOf(list).Kind() == reflect.Array {
        listvalue := reflect.ValueOf(list)
        for i := 0; i < listvalue.Len(); i++ {
            if target == listvalue.Index(i).Interface() {
                return true, i
            }
        }
    }
    if reflect.TypeOf(target).Kind() == reflect.String && reflect.TypeOf(list).Kind() == reflect.String {
        return strings.Contains(list.(string), target.(string)), strings.Index(list.(string), target.(string))
    }
    return false, -1
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think `map[x]bool` is more useful than `map[x]struct{}`.

Indexing the map for an item that isn't present will return `false`. so instead of `_, ok := m[X]`, you can just say `m[X]`.

This makes it easy to nest inclusion tests in expressions.

Comment: This is good, but keep in mind that struct{} has space complexity of 0 while bool has more

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *reflect* package to iterate over an interface whose concrete type is a slice:

```
func HasElem(s interface{}, elem interface{}) bool {
    arrV := reflect.ValueOf(s)

    if arrV.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < arrV.Len(); i++ {

            // XXX - panics if slice element points to an unexported struct field
            // see https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface
            if arrV.Index(i).Interface() == elem {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jL5UD7yCNq

Comment: Sure you can use the reflect package but just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  Reflection is very expensive.

Comment: In actual application code no, you shouldn't do this. It is expensive.
However, for unit tests, it doesn't matter so much and is very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure generics are needed here. You just need a contract for your desired behavior. Doing the following is no more than what you would have to do in other languages if you wanted your own objects to behave themselves in collections, by overriding Equals() and GetHashCode() for instance.

```
type Identifiable interface{
    GetIdentity() string
}

func IsIdentical(this Identifiable, that Identifiable) bool{
    return (&this == &that) || (this.GetIdentity() == that.GetIdentity())
}

func contains(s []Identifiable, e Identifiable) bool {
    for _, a := range s {
        if IsIdentical(a,e) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: "is no more than what you would have to do in other languages" isn't really true - e.g. in C# `Contains()` is implemented on `List<T>`, so you only ever have to implement `Equals()` for that work.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing **@Adolfo's** answer (and other answers here), the [Contains](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#Contains) function won't be something experimental anymore. Starting with **GO v1.21**, which will be released during **August 2023**, the aforementioned [`slice` package](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master) will be included into the core library (besides some other interesting packages like `map` and `cmp`), making it possible to run a linear search over a slice of elements (**O(N) time complexity**).

Additionally you will have some other interesting variations for searching an element (or elements) within a slice, like the new [ContainsFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#ContainsFunc), which reports whether at least one element `e` of s satisfies `f(e)`. You can check this at the example below, which is taken from the actual docs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    numbers := []int{0, 42, -10, 8}
    hasNegative := slices.ContainsFunc(numbers, func(n int) bool {
        return n < 0
    })
    fmt.Println("Has a negative:", hasNegative)
    hasOdd := slices.ContainsFunc(numbers, func(n int) bool {
        return n%2 != 0
    })
    fmt.Println("Has an odd number:", hasOdd)
}
```

Also, to keep in mind, if you are working with a sorted slice and you want to reduce the time complexity when searching for an element (O(logN)), you will also be able to use the [`BinarySearch`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#BinarySearch) and the [`BinarySearchFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#BinarySearchFunc) functions, which will also come with this new package.

Finally, if you want to make the search constant in time (**O(1)**), I would go for the approach suggested by **@tux21b** in the voted answer by using maps.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not feasable to use a map for finding items based on a key, you can consider the [goderive](https://github.com/awalterschulze/goderive) tool. Goderive generates a type specific implementation of a contains method, making your code both readable and efficient.

Example;

```
type Foo struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
} 

func Test(m Foo) bool {
     var allItems []Foo
     return deriveContainsFoo(allItems, m)
}
```

To generate the deriveContainsFoo method:

- Install goderive with `go get -u github.com/awalterschulze/goderive`
- Run `goderive ./...` in your workspace folder

This method will be generated for deriveContains:

```
func deriveContainsFoo(list []Foo, item Foo) bool {
    for _, v := range list {
        if v == item {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Goderive has support for quite some other useful helper methods to apply a functional programming style in go.

Answer (score 1):

The go style:

```
func Contains(n int, match func(i int) bool) bool {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if match(i) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}


s := []string{"a", "b", "c", "o"}
// test if s contains "o"
ok := Contains(len(s), func(i int) bool {
    return s[i] == "o"
})
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, nor gives additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `byte` slice, you can use `bytes` package:

```
package main
import "bytes"

func contains(b []byte, sub byte) bool {
   return bytes.Contains(b, []byte{sub})
}

func main() {
   b := contains([]byte{10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 13)
   println(b)
}
```

Or `suffixarray` package:

```
package main
import "index/suffixarray"

func contains(b []byte, sub byte) bool {
   return suffixarray.New(b).Lookup([]byte{sub}, 1) != nil
}

func main() {
   b := contains([]byte{10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 13)
   println(b)
}
```

If you have an `int` slice, you can use `intsets` package:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets"

func main() {
   var s intsets.Sparse
   for n := 10; n < 20; n++ {
      s.Insert(n)
   }
   b := s.Has(16)
   println(b)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/bytes
- https://golang.org/pkg/index/suffixarray
- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets

Answer (score 0):

```
func contains(slice []string, item string) bool {
    for _, s := range slice {
        if s == item {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I created the following Contains function using reflect package.
This function can be used for various types like int32 or struct etc.

```golang
// Contains returns true if an element is present in a slice
func Contains(list interface{}, elem interface{}) bool {
    listV := reflect.ValueOf(list)

    if listV.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < listV.Len(); i++ {
            item := listV.Index(i).Interface()

            target := reflect.ValueOf(elem).Convert(reflect.TypeOf(item)).Interface()
            if ok := reflect.DeepEqual(item, target); ok {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Usage of contains function  is below

```golang
// slice of int32
containsInt32 := Contains([]int32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3)
fmt.Println("contains int32:", containsInt32)

// slice of float64
containsFloat64 := Contains([]float64{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5}, 4.4)
fmt.Println("contains float64:", containsFloat64)


// slice of struct
type item struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
}
list := []item{
    item{
        ID:   "1",
        Name: "test1",
    },
    item{
        ID:   "2",
        Name: "test2",
    },
    item{
        ID:   "3",
        Name: "test3",
    },
}
target := item{
    ID:   "2",
    Name: "test2",
}
containsStruct := Contains(list, target)
fmt.Println("contains struct:", containsStruct)

// Output:
// contains int32: true
// contains float64: true
// contains struct: true
```

Please see here for more details:
https://github.com/glassonion1/xgo/blob/main/contains.go

Answer (score -2):

There are several [packages that can help](https://github.com/wesovilabs/koazee), but this one seems promising:

https://github.com/wesovilabs/koazee

```
var numbers = []int{1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 3}
contains, _ := stream.Contains(7)
fmt.Printf("stream.Contains(7): %v\n", contains)
```

Answer (score -3):

It might be considered a bit 'hacky' but depending the size and contents of the slice, you can join the slice together and do a string search.

For example you have a slice containing single word values (e.g. "yes", "no", "maybe"). These results are appended to a slice. If you want to check if this slice contains any "maybe" results, you may use

```
exSlice := ["yes", "no", "yes", "maybe"]
if strings.Contains(strings.Join(exSlice, ","), "maybe") {
  fmt.Println("We have a maybe!")
}
```

How suitable this is really depends on the size of the slice and length of its members. There may be performance or suitability issues for large slices or long values, but for smaller slices of finite size and simple values it is a valid one-liner to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Will not work for situation where elements have similar text but not exactly the same
`exSlice := ["yes and no", "maybe", "maybe another"]`

Comment: This is a rather nice approach for achieving a quick-and-dirty one-liner solution.  You just need to require an unambiguous delimiter (could be a comma) and do the extra work to bracket both strings: `","+strings.Join(exSlice,",")+","`, and `",maybe,"`