# Does Go have "if x in" construct similar to Python?

Tags: if-statement, go

How can I check if `x` is in an array **without** iterating over the entire array, using Go? Does the language have a construct for this?

Like in Python:

```py
if "x" in array: 
  # do something
```

Comment: AFAIK, There is not shorthand for that in go. Internally, python also iterates over the array, there is no going around that.

Comment: BTW, an important note to this is that there *is no way* to do this (as you ask for) "**[w]ithout** iterating over the entire array". Making such loops explicit (or behind a function such as `strings.Index`) helps make it more obvious what the code is doing. I get the impression that perhaps you think Python's `in array:` is doing something fast/magic. AFAIK it isn't. Making the loop explicit helps make the writer (and all readers) aware and consider other implementations (e.g. a map).

Comment: However, if "x" in set is indeed very fast.

Comment: I don't think we're asking for a programatically fast approach, we're just asking for a concise one (and still haven't got...)

Comment: @RobertoAlsina A Set, Which also Go lacks.

Answer (score 552, accepted):

There is no built-in operator to do it in Go. You need to iterate over the array. You can write your own function to do it, like this:

```
func stringInSlice(a string, list []string) bool {
    for _, b := range list {
        if b == a {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Or in Go 1.18 or newer, you can use [`slices.Contains`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains) (from golang.org/x/exp/slices).

If you want to be able to check for membership without iterating over the whole list, you need to use a map instead of an array or slice, like this:

```
visitedURL := map[string]bool {
    "http://www.google.com": true,
    "https://paypal.com": true,
}
if visitedURL[thisSite] {
    fmt.Println("Already been here.")
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without specifying type? let's say if i want just a general needleInHaystack(needle, haystack) function without separate methods for every single type

Comment: It could be done with the reflect package, but it would be fairly inefficient (probably about as slow as if you wrote it out in a dynamic language like Python). Other than that, no. That's what people mean when they say that Go doesn't have generics.

Comment: Anyone stumbled upon this answer must note that you CANNOT sort maps. Big downside to using go maps.

Comment: you can't sort maps (objects) in Javascript also. It's a v8 *bug* that objects return values in alphabetically sorted order.

Comment: maps aren't sorted in most languages -- that's par for the course for a map data structure (hashmap).

Comment: @Hejazzman many other mainstream languages have sorted maps in addition to hash maps, e.g. `map` in C++ and `SortedMap` in Java

Comment: I find new things I dislike about Go almost every day. Feels like we took a step back

Comment: @andybalholm Go now has generics, how could this answer be updated/can this now be optimized?

Comment: You could write an `inSlice` function that would work for all comparable types. It would be as fast as the `stringInSlice` function, but no faster.

Comment: Come to think of it, there's a function for that in golang.org/x/exp/slices. I've edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 166):

Another solution if the list contains static values.

eg: checking for a valid value from a list of valid values:

```
func IsValidCategory(category string) bool {
    switch category {
    case
        "auto",
        "news",
        "sport",
        "music":
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Yeah, what if your "valid values" come from a database?

Comment: Yeah, this is neat but only when these values can be defined in advance.

Comment: @RonanDejhero then i could use WHERE :myValue IN (subquery) :)

Comment: This is neat comparing to the top answer

Comment: as the other comments mention, this is great for the case where the values are constants! Otherwise, I recommend the accepted answer.

Comment: Its also quite a bit faster compared to array loop. So helpful in case the list is static and called in a large filtering loop.

Answer (score 58):

This is quote from the book "Programming in Go: Creating Applications for the 21st Century":

> Using a simple linear search like this is the only option for unsorted
>   data and is fine for small slices (up to hundreds of items). But for
>   larger slices—especially if we are performing searches repeatedly—the
>   linear search is very inefficient, on average requiring half the items
>   to be compared each time.
>
> Go provides a sort.Search() method which uses the binary search
>   algorithm: This requires the comparison of only log2(n) items (where n
>   is the number of items) each time. To put this in perspective, a
>   linear search of 1000000 items requires 500000 comparisons on average,
>   with a worst case of 1000000 comparisons; a binary search needs at
>   most 20 comparisons, even in the worst case.

```
files := []string{"Test.conf", "util.go", "Makefile", "misc.go", "main.go"}
target := "Makefile"
sort.Strings(files)
i := sort.Search(len(files),
    func(i int) bool { return files[i] >= target })
if i < len(files) && files[i] == target {
    fmt.Printf("found \"%s\" at files[%d]\n", files[i], i)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/UIndYQ8FeW

Comment: This only makes sense if you do repeated searches. Otherwise you've got complexity n*log(n)*log(n) for the sort and binary search, versus just n for the linear search.

Comment: It's actually just `n*log(n) + log(n)`, as it's two consequent independent operations

Answer (score 46):

Just had a similar question and decided to try out some of the suggestions in this thread.

I've benchmarked best and worst-case scenarios of 3 types of lookup:

- using a map
- using a list
- using a switch statement

Here's the function code:

```golang
func belongsToMap(lookup string) bool {
list := map[string]bool{
    "900898296857": true,
    "900898302052": true,
    "900898296492": true,
    "900898296850": true,
    "900898296703": true,
    "900898296633": true,
    "900898296613": true,
    "900898296615": true,
    "900898296620": true,
    "900898296636": true,
}
if _, ok := list[lookup]; ok {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
}


func belongsToList(lookup string) bool {
list := []string{
    "900898296857",
    "900898302052",
    "900898296492",
    "900898296850",
    "900898296703",
    "900898296633",
    "900898296613",
    "900898296615",
    "900898296620",
    "900898296636",
}
for _, val := range list {
    if val == lookup {
        return true
    }
}
return false
}

func belongsToSwitch(lookup string) bool {
switch lookup {
case
    "900898296857",
    "900898302052",
    "900898296492",
    "900898296850",
    "900898296703",
    "900898296633",
    "900898296613",
    "900898296615",
    "900898296620",
    "900898296636":
    return true
}
return false
}
```

Best-case scenarios pick the first item in lists, worst-case ones use nonexistent value.

Here are the results:

```
BenchmarkBelongsToMapWorstCase-4         2000000           787 ns/op
BenchmarkBelongsToSwitchWorstCase-4     2000000000           0.35 ns/op
BenchmarkBelongsToListWorstCase-4       100000000           14.7 ns/op
BenchmarkBelongsToMapBestCase-4          2000000           683 ns/op
BenchmarkBelongsToSwitchBestCase-4      100000000           10.6 ns/op
BenchmarkBelongsToListBestCase-4        100000000           10.4 ns/op
```

Switch wins all the way, worst case is surpassingly quicker than best case.

Maps are the worst and list is closer to switch.

So the moral is:
If you have a static, reasonably small list, switch statement is the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if Go optimizes this case, but does it make a difference if you move the initialization of the list/map outside the test function?

Comment: I'm curious to see how the comparison would play out with a sorted list and whether the sort would be worth it

Comment: What about `:` instead of `,` in the switch statement? Does it make it faster?

Comment: I tried using multiple `case` statements instead of a single case. Results are sensibly the same with both functions.

Comment: Nothing like providing a solution and using a benchmark to compare it to the most 'obvious' other solutions — backing up your suggestion with _data_, not speculation! Thank you — I'll stick to switches, since I have a fixed, static amount of checks...

Comment: Something I'm not getting... how can it be faster to "NOT" be in there? is this some kind of hashmap-ing optimization done by Go? Is it because they're all "strings" that starts with the same stuff (900898[23]) and it's checked rune by rune ?

Comment: This benchmark is quite badly flawed. You're initialising the structure to be searched within the same method that you're benchmarking.

I re-implemented this & put the initialisation of those lists & maps into the `func Bench...` methods. When not including the map initialisation or the slice initialisation, searching the map is more than twice as fast by the time you have 10 keys in the structure to be searched. This difference only gets worse for the slice as the number of entries increases.

Comment: @DuncanGener8, can you share your test method and results in a separate answer?

Answer (score 29):

The above example using sort is close, but in the case of strings simply use SearchString:

```
files := []string{"Test.conf", "util.go", "Makefile", "misc.go", "main.go"}
target := "Makefile"
sort.Strings(files)
i := sort.SearchStrings(files, target)
if i < len(files) && files[i] == target {
    fmt.Printf("found \"%s\" at files[%d]\n", files[i], i)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchStrings

Comment: This answer looks like a less informative copy paste of the answer below, which happened before this answer.

Comment: @cytinus What answer are you referring to?  That's the only one I see based on `sort.SearchStrings`.

Comment: I got a 100x speedup on repeated searches through a large slice.

Answer (score 16):

This is as close as I can get to the natural feel of Python's "in" operator. You have to define your own type. Then you can extend the functionality of that type by adding a method like "has" which behaves like you'd hope.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type StrSlice []string

func (list StrSlice) Has(a string) bool {
    for _, b := range list {
        if b == a {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    var testList = StrSlice{"The", "big", "dog", "has", "fleas"}

    if testList.Has("dog") {
        fmt.Println("Yay!")
    }
}
```

I have a utility library where I define a few common things like this for several types of slices, like those containing integers or my own other structs.

Yes, it runs in linear time, but that's not the point. The point is to ask and learn what common language constructs Go has and doesn't have. It's a good exercise. Whether this answer is silly or useful is up to the reader.

Answer (score 10):

In Go <strike>1.18+</strike>1.21+, you can now declare generic `Contains` function or import in <strike>[the experimental slice package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains)</strike> [the built-in slice package](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Contains). It works for any comparable type

```golang
func Contains[T comparable](arr []T, x T) bool {
    for _, v := range arr {
        if v == x {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

and use it like this:

```golang
if Contains(arr, "x") {
    // do something
}
```

or by importing

```golang
// func[S ~[]E, E comparable](s S, v E) bool
if slices.Contains(arr, "x") {
    // do something
}
```

[which I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802740/6056991)

Answer (score 8):

Another option is using a map as a set.  You use just the keys and having the value be something like a boolean that's always true.  Then you can easily check if the map contains the key or not.  This is useful if you need the behavior of a set, where if you add a value multiple times it's only in the set once.

Here's a simple example where I add random numbers as keys to a map.  If the same number is generated more than once it doesn't matter, it will only appear in the final map once.  Then I use a simple if check to see if a key is in the map or not.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    var MAX int = 10

    m := make(map[int]bool)

    for i := 0; i <= MAX; i++ {
        m[rand.Intn(MAX)] = true
    }

    for i := 0; i <= MAX; i++ {
        if _, ok := m[i]; ok {
            fmt.Printf("%v is in map\n", i)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%v is not in map\n", i)
        }
    }
}
```

[Here it is on the go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dliU4qXvGG)

Answer (score 2):

try `lo`: https://github.com/samber/lo#contains

```
present := lo.Contains[int]([]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5)
```