# Check if a value is in a list

Tags: dictionary, go, set

Does Go have something similar to Python's `in` keyword? I want to check if a value is in a list.

For example in Python:

```
x = 'red'

if x in ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']:
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

In Go I've come up with using the set idiom but I don't think it's ideal as I have to specify a int value that I'm not using.

```
x := "red"

valid := map[string]int{"red": 0, "green": 0,"yellow": 0, "blue": 0}

if _, ok := valid[x]; ok {
    fmt.Println("found")
} else {
    fmt.Println("not found")
}
```

I understand having an `in` keyword is probably related to generics. Is there a way to do this using go generate or something?

Comment: Also see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323767/how-to-if-x-in-array-in-golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323767/how-to-if-x-in-array-in-golang)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a `map[string]bool` as a set. When testing and a key is not in the map, the zero value for `bool` is returned which is `false`.

So fill the map with the valid values as keys and `true` as value. If a tested key-value is in the map, its stored `true` value will be the result. If a tested key-value is not in the map, the zero value for the value type is returned which is `false`.

Using this, the test becomes this simple:

```
valid := map[string]bool{"red": true, "green": true, "yellow": true, "blue": true}

if valid[x] {
    fmt.Println("found")
} else {
    fmt.Println("not found")
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/wBV4ZnBzEH) (with the variants mentioned below).

This is mentioned in the blog post: [**Go maps in action: Exploiting zero values**](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_4.)

**Note:**

If you have many valid values, since all the values to be stored in the map are `true`, it may be more compact to use a slice to list the valid values and use a `for range` loop to initialize your map, something like this:

```
for _, v := range []string{"red", "green", "yellow", "blue"} {
    valid[v] = true
}
```

**Note #2:**

If you don't want to go with the `for range` loop initialization, you can still optimize it a little by creating an untyped (or `bool`-typed) one-letter `const`:

```
const t = true
valid := map[string]bool{"red": t, "green": t, "yellow": t, "blue": t}
```

Comment: For large sets, using a map[string]struct{} instead of a map[string]bool might save space because the empty struct occupies zero space. Testing for existence needs to use the two-value form `_, exists := valid[x]`. Create the map in the first place using empty struct literals `{}` instead of the bool `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Go 1.21, you can use the [slices](https://pkg.go.dev/slices) package:

```
package main

import (
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    colors := []string{"red", "green", "yellow", "blue"}
    containsRed := slices.Contains(colors, "red") //true
    containsBlack := slices.Contains(colors, "black") //false

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `map[string]bool` in the other answer is a good option. Another method
is `map[string]struct{}`, which uses slightly less memory:

```
package main

func main() {
   x, valid := "red", map[string]struct{}{
      "red": {}, "green": {}, "yellow": {}, "blue": {},
   }
   if _, ok := valid[x]; ok {
      println("found")
   } else {
      println("not found")
   }
}
```

You could also wrap it in a type:

```
package main

type set map[string]struct{}

func newSet(slice []string) set {
   s := make(set)
   for _, each := range slice {
      s[each] = struct{}{}
   }
   return s
}

func (s set) has(v string) bool {
   _, ok := s[v]
   return ok
}

func main() {
   x := "red"
   if newSet([]string{"red", "green", "yellow", "blue"}).has(x) {
      println("found")
   } else {
      println("not found")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using generics in Go >= 1.18

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// In is a generic function that checks if a given item exists in a slice of
// items of a comparable type. It returns true if the item is found, otherwise
// it returns false.
func In[Item comparable](items []Item, item Item) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(items); i++ {
        if items[i] == item {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(In([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3))
}
```

```bash
true
```

Go Playground https://go.dev/play/p/ovhlcaBz0Uc